# 96 Chevy caprice 5.7L

Tags: coolant-reservoir

My 96 Chevy caprice engine coolat reservoir overflow tank have 2 lines running to it I ordered a new reservoir and it only has one slot where a line can go is that a problem And how do I run the lines

Comment: You ordered or were shipped the wrong part, send it back and get the right part.

Comment: Pictures are helpful when asking this type of question.